# Drop down list from MySQL in HTML page

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

im trying to put a drop down list generated from mysql in html page , the thing is this code work fine in a php page but it doesnt in html page , I've put it in a php tags yet nothing was shown , I would appreciate any help 
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <title>Add Qustions</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="saveQ.php" method="post" >

  <br />
  <?php   $connectdb = mysql_connect('localhost','root','sara') or die ("Not Connect");
  if (!$connectdb)
  {
      die('Could not connect :'. mysql_errno());
  }
  $selestdb  = mysql_select_db('iexa', $connectdb) or die ("not selected database");
   $qu = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Name FROM Course ORDER BY ID asc") or die ("mysql error");
    echo "Choose the course that you want to create the test for : <br /> ";
    echo " <select name='courseID' >Course</option>";
    echo "<option value=0>Course </option>";
     $curvalue=2;
    while  ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qu)){
    echo '<option value="' .$row[ID].'">' .$row[ID].' ' .$row[Name].'</option>';
    $curvalue = $curvalue+1;
     }
     echo "</select> "; ?>
     <br />
      /// some other unrelated code here 
    <input type="submit" value="Save Question" />
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this code work fine in a php page but it doesnt in html page". With the usual default settings for most servers, any script that contains PHP code must have a valid PHP extension, like .php or .phtml.

Comment: PHP does not work in HTML, but HTML works in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like to echo out html in PHP so i use this method, in any case your issue is html based and not php based...

### Example PHP Model to Query DB :

```
<?php
$selectdb  = mysql_select_db('iexa', $connectdb) or die ("not selected database");
$qu = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Name FROM Course ORDER BY ID asc") or die ("mysql error");
?>
```

### Example View File to Handle the DOM and html.

```
<p>Choose the course that you want to create the test for:</p><br />
<select name="courseID">
    <option value="0">0 Course</option>
    <option value="1">1 Course</option>
  <?php while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qu) ): ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['ID'].' '.$row['Name']; ?></option>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
```

**In short, you have an error here:**
`echo " <select name='courseID' >Course</option>";`.

**It should be:** `echo " <select name='courseID' >Course</select>";`

---

**Also, you dont need to set `$curvalue = $curvalue+1;` You can simply do `$curvalue++;` IE:**

```
<?php
  while  ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qu)){
  <select name="courseID">
  <option value="<?= $row['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['ID'].' '.$row['Name']; ?></option>
  </select>
   $curvalue++;
 }
```

**Also note**
that its considered best practice to not mix DOM with Server side code. IE you should put the while statement and select boxes in a seperate php view file that iterates through things, rather than using `echo`. This way there is less server processing and more client side processing.

Comment: the example code has been udpated, its still ideal to remove the `mysql_fetch_assoc` from the "view file" and pass in an array to a foreach loop instead of using while.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't look like `$curvalue` is used at all. You can completely remove it. Also, granted, it is good to use a code structure, like MVC, but it seems kinda outside the scope of this question IMO.

Comment: Hold on, I just looked at your examples better. It looks like you are only fetching one row from the database. One call to `mysql_fetch_assoc` fetches **one** row from the database and stores it in an associative array, with each entry representing one **column** from the singluar row. So the point of the while-loop is to continually fetch rows until there are no more rows to fetch.

Comment: So your `foreach` loop is looping through the columns of one row.

Comment: yeah, confusing ActiveRecord from CI with old school base php stuf.. i reupdated it. I do most of my db stuff in CodeIgniter or FuelPHP which iterates through for you and provides an array of all rows returned.. Forgot `mysql_fetch_assoc()` doesnt do that out of the box, in which case your previous comment stands true $curvalue is useless.

Answer (score 1):

I think this script is what you wanted to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Add Qustions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="saveQ.php" method="post">
        <br />
        <?php  
            $connectdb = mysql_connect('localhost','root','sara') or die ("Not Connect");
            if (!$connectdb) die('Could not connect :'. mysql_errno());

            echo "          Choose the course that you want to create the test for: <br />
            <select name=\"courseID\">
                <option value=\"0\">Course </option>\n";

            $selestdb  = mysql_select_db('iexa', $connectdb) or die ("not selected database");
            $qu = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Name FROM Course ORDER BY ID asc") or die ("mysql error");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qu))
                echo "              <option value=\"{$row["ID"]}\">{$row["ID"]} {$row["Name"]}</option>\n";

            echo "          </select> ";
        ?>
        <br />
        <!-- some other unrelated code here -->
        <input type="submit" value="Save Question" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Your script's name should end with a PHP extension, like .php or .phtml.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are doing it like this:

```
echo " <select name='courseID' >Course</option>";
```

Change it to:

```
echo "<select name='courseID'>";
```

Comment: That seems wrong as well...did you mean `<select name='courseID'><option>Course</option>`?

Comment: @Travesty3 In case you skipped the code, the OP is having and `echo <option>` in just the next statement.

Comment: OK, that's fine, but what is the point of `Course` in your example?

Comment: Oh! Totally didn't see it. I guess it's good night time now. :)